# How to get a single value from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas.

I am trying to get a particular value based on the value in another column. However the output is coming as a list of values rather than just one value, while I can try and make do with this, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.
`prem_ce'

```
OpenInterest  Volume  BidPrice  OfferPrice  StrikePrice  prem_ratio
6     8,296,000   3,934      4.15        4.25        100.0         3.0   
7    10,872,000   3,981      1.60        1.65        110.0         2.0   
8     8,692,000   1,302      0.70        0.75        120.0         2.0   
9     5,524,000   1,118      0.35        0.40        130.0         1.0   
10    3,108,000     110      0.20        0.25        140.0         1.0   
11    2,692,000      55      0.10        0.15        150.0         1.0   
12    1,908,000       4      0.05        0.10        160.0         0.0   
13    1,176,000       8      0.05        0.10        170.0         0.0   
14      920,000       6      0.05        0.10        180.0         0.0   
15      192,000       1      0.05        0.10        190.0         0.0   
16      336,000       7      0.05        0.10        200.0         0.0   
17      168,000       2      0.00        0.10        210.0         0.0   
18       24,000       2      0.00        0.10        220.0         0.0   
19            0       0      0.00        0.10        230.0         0.0   
20            0       0      0.00        0.15        240.0         NaN
```

I tried the following:

```
for ratio in prem_ce['prem_ratio']:
    if ratio >= 2 and ratio is not 'NaN':
        x = int(ratio)
        ratio_row = prem_ce.index[prem_ce['prem_ratio'] == ratio]
        ce_strike_sell = prem_ce['StrikePrice'][ratio_row].values
        print(ce_strike_sell)
```

I get the following output:

```
[ 100.] 
[ 110.  120.]
[ 110.  120.]
```

I have made the `prem_ratio` by

```
prem_ce['prem_ratio'] = prem_ce['BidPrice'] / prem_ce['OfferPrice'].shift(-1)
```

Now I am trying to put both the `StrikePrice` used to calculate `prem_ratio` into `variables`.

I can't understand why I am getting a `list` and that the first `list` has only one value while the other two have 2 values.

Edit--

I expected the program to loop through each row and give me 1 value when condition was satisfied. i.e. 100.0, 110.0, 120.0 in 3 loops.

I expected the output to be,

1st loop: `ce_strike_sell = 100.0`

2nd loop: `ce_strike_sell = 110.0`

3rd loop: `ce_strike_sell = 120.0`

I am not sure if there is a way to do this as I am still very new to pandas

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the line:

```
ratio_row = prem_ce.index[prem_ce['prem_ratio'] == ratio]
```

is selecting all the indexes for which `prem_ratio` is equal to `ratio` and in the dataframe there are multiple rows with same `prem_ratio`

Comment: Thanks, Any way to get the values only?

Comment: I can't understand what output do you exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get a list is, because `prem_ce['StrikePrice'][ratio_row]` is a Series and the property `values` gets you list of values of the Series.

Easier would be something like:

```
prem_ce[prem_ce['prem_ratio'] >= 2]['StrikePrice']
```

This is again a Series.

Answer (score 1):

**I can't understand why I am getting a list and that the first list has only one value while the other two have 2 values.**

Your logic is as follows *for each row*:

1. If `ratio_row >= 2`, find all ratios where `ratio == ratio_row`, where `ratio_row` is the ratio *for that row*.
2. There is one row where `ratio == 3`, but 2 rows where `ratio == 2`. Therefore, you will get 1 value for the first row and 2 values for the next 2 rows.

It's not clear why you expect only one value from each row, or what you want as your expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I expected the program to loop through each row and give me 1 value when condition was satisfied. i.e. 100.0, 110.0, 120.0 in 3 loops. I expected the output to be, after first loop: `ce_strike_sell = 100.0`, 2nd loop: `ce_strike_sell = 110.0` and third loop: `ce_strike_sell = 120.0`. I am not sure if there is a way to do this as I am still very new to pandas.